# How do I redirect to a page and not get a cached copy of the landing page

Tags: http, redirect, browser-cache

I have this php script that logs a user in, sets a cookie and when done, redirects the user to the homepage of the site.

For performance purposes, the landing page is cached but when the page is requested with the redirect after signing in, the browser should not read a cached copy. This is because the server sees that the user is logged in and responds with extra buttons and such.

I am adding a query string at the end of the URL (`?nocache=1`) as a workaround but this is not a nice way to do it.

I wonder if it's possible to tell the browser to redirect to a URL without reading the landing page from the cache and actually ask for a response from the server.

Comment: By the way the page is cached at the client side by sending the header `Cache-control`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a workaround:

I set another cookie after the login operation: "just-logged-in"
Added some javascript to the landing page that checks for the cookie "just-logged-in" and if it finds the cookie after deleting it (to avoid a reload loop) runs `location.reload(true)` which reloads the page ignoring the cache.

This results in another redirection but since the first one is read from the cache we have two HTTP requests as we expected.